# Adding sources for shared library in GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb, shared-libraries

How to add source code of `some_shared_library.so` into `gdb`.

I've tried to use `dir` command but it has not helped.

Answer (score 2):

In order for GDB to know what sources match your `some_shared_library.so`, you must build it with debugging info (usually `-g` flag).

Once you've done that (and it sounds like you haven't), on many platforms (e.g. Linux) GDB will find the sources automatically. On other platforms, `dir` is the right command to tell GDB where the sources are.

Comment: Thanks but i've alredy tried it. And i'm still unable to see sources of shared library in `gdb`